# Azure Function app queue trigger create time trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to have a queue trigger create a 5 minute time trigger that then checks if the queued item still exists.

I'm trying to use Function Apps to give user a grace time. Each user can have a different grace time depending on settings on their account. I was thinking I could write a to a queue and fire the queue trigger to call a timer trigger that uses the users time setting to check back and see if the user completed his task before grace. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You could send a message to a Service Bus queue and set `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUTC` property to now + 5 minutes. The message will be processed after the specified time.

For Storage Queues, you could use `CloudQueue.AddMessage` overload with `initialVisibilityDelay` parameter for the same purpose.